# Java crawler with custom file save ability

Tags: java, web-crawler

I'm looking for a open-source web crawler written in Java which, **in addition to usual web crawler features such as depth/multi-threaded/etc.** has the ability to custom handling each file type.

To be more precise, when a file is downloaded (or is going to be downloaded), I want to handle the saving operation of the files. The HTML files should be saved in a different repository, images to another location and other files somewhere else. Also, the repository could be not just a simple file system.

I've heard a lot about [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org). Does it have the ability to do this? I'm looking to achieve this as simple and fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on assumption that you want a lot of control over how crawler works, I would recommend [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/). There are many [examples](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/), so you can get quick glimpse of how things are working.

You could easily handle resources based on their content type (take a look at [Page.java](http://code.google.com/searchframe#cRPXZ1h-0hE/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/Page.java) class - it is class of object that contains information about fetched resource).

There is no limitations regarding repository. You can use anything you wish.

Comment: It's got basically all the things I need, but one thing that I have in mind is that how can `crawler4j` compete against `Nutch`? Is its features rich enough? My project will expand over time and I don't want to have to switch to something else later.

Comment: `Nutch` seems very robust but advanced crawler so I am not sure it will be fast and simple solution. IMO and based on you requirements  `crawler4j` will suffice. If you'll decide to use it, please let us know how your project is going.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure for now it will suffice, I'm just thinking about the future. Of course, I'll give feedback if I use it. I have to say your architecture is very nice and easy to learn.

Comment: I am not author of this project. I am just curious whether it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks anyway. I'll let you know.